# Вычисление количества символов в переменной (C#)

Tags: c#, int

Какой из вариантов вычисления количества символов в числе эффективнее.

через перебор

```
for(ulong t = degre_of; t > 0; t = t / 10)
{
    deg_lenght++;
}
```

или через длину строки

```
deg_lenght = degre_of.ToString().Length;
```

Comment: Я думаю, что второй операций меньше выполняется. Ты попробуй отладить или проведи Nunit тесты и увидишь точно)

Comment: Можно добавить таймер и проверить? Вот еще вариант (int)Math.Log10(degre_of) + 1;

Comment: Меньше операций не аргумент, строковые операции долго работают

Comment: Общего правильного ответа здесь быть не может. Правдивый ответ результат даст только прямое измерение, да и то, оно может быть правдивым только для данного компьютера/компилятора. Но из общих соображений предположу, что первый пример будет выполняться быстрее, потому что во втором примере вызов неявно делает то же самое, чтобы извлечь отдельные цифры числа.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем гадать, давайте протестируем.

Ставим **Benchmark.NET**, пишем вот такой тест. Так же добавлю метод с логарифмом, который предложил @demonplus в комментариях.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyBenchmark>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class MyBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public int MathTest()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (uint number = 1; number <= 10000000; number++)
        {
            int length = 0;
            for (uint t = number; t > 0; t /= 10)
            {
                length++;
            }
            total += length;
        }
        return total;
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public int SwitchTest()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (uint number = 1; number <= 10000000; number++)
        {
            total += number switch 
            {
                < 10 => 1,
                < 100 => 2,
                < 1000 => 3,
                < 10000 => 4,
                < 100000 => 5,
                < 1000000 => 6,
                < 10000000 => 7,
                < 100000000 => 8,
                < 1000000000 => 9,
                _ => 10,
            };
        }
        return total;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int StringTest()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (uint number = 1; number <= 10000000; number++)
        {
            total += number.ToString().Length;
        }
        return total;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int Log10Test()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (uint number = 1; number <= 10000000; number++)
        {
            total += (int)Math.Log10(number) + 1;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Считаем сумму длин всех чисел от 1 до миллиона. Если вывести в консоль, результат всех методов будет одинаковый.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(MathTest());
Console.WriteLine(SwitchTest());
Console.WriteLine(StringTest());
Console.WriteLine(Log10Test());
```

```
68888897
68888897
68888897
68888897
```

Запускаем тест производительности

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19042.1288 (20H2/October2020Update)
Intel Core i7-9700K CPU 3.60GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.402
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.11 (5.0.1121.47308), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.11 (5.0.1121.47308), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MathTest | 38.51 ms | 0.118 ms | 0.104 ms | - | - |
| SwitchTest | 11.11 ms | 0.070 ms | 0.065 ms | - | - |
| StringTest | 121.48 ms | 1.000 ms | 0.886 ms | 63600.0000 | 399,199,987 B |
| Log10Test | 52.27 ms | 0.108 ms | 0.101 ms | - | - |

И видим, что метод с использованием строки не только в 7 раз медленнее, чем метод с циклом, но еще и скушал дополнительно 400 МБ памяти для работы. И цикл все-таки оказался быстрее десятичного логарифма.

Кстати, в методе с циклом есть баг, который я просто обошел в тестах, если число равно `0`, то метод со строкой вернет `1`, а метод с циклом - `0`. Но вы уже наверняка поняли, как это исправить.

---

UPD: Добавил тест с вариантом `switch`.

Comment: Немного неожиданно, что цикл быстрее логарифма, причем на M1 - в два раза, 32.16 ms vs 72.97 ms

Comment: @PashaPash и это еще без SIMD :)

Comment: прямо хочется конкурс объявить за вариант с векторизацией :)

Comment: @PashaPash именно для этого теста? Или для каждого числа в отдельности? Если первое - то легче легкого. Если второе, надо подумать.

Comment: сомневаюсь, что для одного числа имеет смысл. для всех - наверное, вообще можно формулу вывести.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099524/1988244 - вариант с лесенкой if-ов самый быстрый

Comment: @PashaPash обновил пост.

Comment: @PashaPash представляю себе эту лесенку в реальном проекте... хотя может, это самое узкое место всего проекта :)

Comment: @PashaPash ага, для `long`, с учетом отрицательных. Но практического применения этому алгоритму я вообще не вижу. На практике `.ToString()` прекрасно отработает.